# Duplicate number in 2nd row, n number of times, where n is the number in the first row

Tags: awk

I have text files that each have a single column of numbers:

```
2
3
4
```

I want to duplicate the second line `n` times, where `n` is the number in the first row, so the output looks like this:

```
3
3
```

I've done something similar in `awk` but can't seem to figure out this specific example.

Comment: Please show your work/code.

Comment: `I want to duplicate the second line`. Where's your second line? Usually people like to see an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{n=$1;} NR==2{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print; exit;}' file
3
3
```

#### How it works

- `NR==1{n=$1;}`

  When we reach the first row, save the number in variable `n`.
- `NR==2{for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print; exit;}`

  When we reach the second row, print it `n` times and exit.

Answer (score 0):

just for fun

```
 read c d < <(head -2 file) | yes $d | head -n $c
```

extract first two rows, assign to c and d; repeat $d forever but get first $c rows.

Comment: I like the creativity.  Your command, however, as written, did not work for me.  The following variation did work: `{ read c; read d; } < <(head -2 file); yes $d | head -n $c`